# Use referenced module's variables

Tags: python

In my project I have defined 3 python files:

1. `variables.py` (which has some variables, values of which will be filled by users):

   ```
   VMD_name = "DEV56"
   VD_IP = "96.119.86.29"
   VD_username = "Administrator"
   VD_password = "nfV!Nads123Versa"
   ```
2. `helper.py` (which has some useful functions and it needs the variables in variables.py, so I have imported it.

   ```
   import variables
   def execute_job():
       print variables.VMD_name
   ```
3. `creation.py`: Which needs access to the functions of helper.py and variables of variables.py. Since variable.py is already imported in helper.py, I thought I should only import helper.py which in turn will have the variables as well.

   ```
   import helper
   ```

But both the below statements are not working. Please let me know do I need to import variables.py again in creation.py? Won't it be duplicacy?

```
print helper.VMD_name
print helper.variables.VMD_name
```

Comment: `helper.variables.VMD_name` *should* work. As such, we either need a more complete example that actually reproduces the problem, or a detailed error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do (in creation.py):

```
print helper.variables.VMD_name
```

and this will work.

Alternatively change the way you import in helper.py to:

```
from variables import VMD_name
```

And now `print helper.VMD_name` will work in creation.py.

Why does it work like that? When you write `import variables`, the constants in the module `variables` become available in `helper.py` but you still need to prepend the module name in order to access them (i.e. in `helper.py` you should write `variables.VMD_name`). Similarly after you `import helper` in `creation.py` the constants in `helper` are available in `creation` but again you should prepend the module name. For this constant it means you should prepend `helper` to the already existing `variables.VMD_name`.

On the other hand if you import using `from variables import VMD_name` the constant becomes available without a module qualifier in helper.

Answer (score 1):

You have imported the modules `variables` in `helper.py` but haven't imported the variables of the `variables` module. So you can write:

```
import helper

print helper.variables.VMD_name
```

If you want use `helper.VMD_name` instead you should import the variables in  `helper.py`:

```
from variables import *
```